# Flash field doesn't accept numerical keyboard when one use uppercase keyboard

Tags: flash

When using a notebook and I have remarked that I cannot enter numerical character with shift +  a letter to enter number.

Is this a bug in flash ? How to circumvent this ?

Comment: Why use shift? Perhaps you meant numlock?

Comment: Why not :) Well because it's quicker on notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, flash only reads one key press at a time, if you want to haveit read a multi key press you need to code it manually. therefor for it to read shift + something you would need to hard code each of them.

Comment: OK thank you, will try to look at this. For me it's kinda functional bug because from user's point of view one doesn't care about this technical detail. A user would expect Flash field to work the same as in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you or the programmer of the Flash application have restricted numbers in the said textbox, you should be able to enter numbers, regardless of your keyboard configuration, even if you use SHIFT+[LETTER] to enter data.

This is not a bug in Flash.